# using dajax in django

Tags: ajax, django, python, dajaxice

I'm posting this question not because I am getting some errors but because I would like to know how dajax should be used

Here is what I want to do:

I want some links on my homepage (eg. books, authors), when user clicks them, he gets a list of books/authors.

Here is what I'm doing:

When user clicks on books, I call a dajax process. 
Inside ajax.py:

- I get all the books using `books = Book.objects.all()`
- I have a `template = "{% for book in books %}"... blah blah blah`
- I render the template `a = Template(template).render(Context(locals()))`
- I do dajax assign a as innerhtml of some div tag.

Is this the right way to do things?
Instead of writing the template in ajax.py should I open templates from some xyz.html and then render it? Any other good, clean ways to get similar tasks done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading a template from a dedicated template file is in almost any case cleaner. A long python string with HTML in it is not very readable.

Of course you could also send your books via `add_data(data,callback_function)` and write a javascript callback function that populates the list which would be the Dajax way of doing what Thomas Orozco proposed.

But judging from the [pagination example](http://www.dajaxproject.com/pagination/) rendering a template file and sending it to `innerHTML` is 'the right way'.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will load templates instead of using python strings. Another way of doing it would be Dajaxice(callback, {..args..}). But that was making my js ugly. So dajax seems the best for now.

Answer (score 1):

I never heard about `dajax` before (but it looks like the project has gone sightly inactive as the latest commit is ~10 months old), so I'll offer advice that is not directly related to `dajax`.

Basically, what you need to do is to display a list that is retrieved using AJAX. That's pretty trivial using the following tools:

- jQuery (or another JS framework)
- JSON

What you need to do is:

1. Configure one of your views so that it returns a list of books ([look here for the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/))
2. Access this view using your JS framewok of choice (`jQuery.get()` for jQUery)
3. Using your JS framework, update some `<ul>` or `<ol>` on your page by adding the content that you retrieved through your get call (And you could place it in some overlay that you'd display).